# Color inside if statements

Tags: color, conditionals

When I write a list of exercises I usually write the solutions just after the statement and then in order to print or not the solutions I include the following in the preamble.

```
\newif\ifsolns\solnstrue %include solutions
%\newif\ifsolns\solnsfalse %do not include solutions
```

What I would like is for the solutions to be shown in blue, so I include the package `color' and what I do is,

```
\ifsolns{\color{blue}
solution goes here
}\fi
```

I want to do this automatically, instead of including the \color{blue} manually every time the solution starts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest writing your solution(s) inside an environment, that you can then turn on/off. The reason behind this is that you'll then have access to the entire solution text, and can manipulate it (add colour, for example) as needed, including conditioning on placement:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ,xcolor}

\newif\ifsolution
\solutiontrue % Print solutions
%\solutionfalse % Do not print solutions (default)

\NewEnviron{solution}{%
  \ifsolution
    \color{blue}\BODY
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  This is a problem that needs a solution.
  
  \begin{solution}
  This is the solution to the first problem.
  \end{solution}
  
  \item
  This is another problem that doesn't require a solution.
  
  \item
  Here is a final problem requiring some sort of solution.
  
  \begin{solution}
  This is the solution to the third problem.
  \end{solution}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

With `\solutionfalse` (the default):

[image]

With `\solutiontrue`:

[image]

Comment: could you explain how to add several conditions when solution is true? I tried:```\usepackage{environ,xcolor}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\newif\ifsolution
\solutiontrue % Print solutions
%\solutionfalse % Do not print solutions

\NewEnviron{solution}{
  \ifsolution
    \color{blue}\newwatermark[allpages,color=red!20,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{Solutions}\BODY
    
  \fi
} ``` in order to add a watermark but it does not work.

Comment: @inquisitor: The [CTAN entry for `xwatermark`](//ctan.org/pkg/xwatermark) mentions "[the package] is currently unmaintained and does not work with modern LaTeX releases." That's what is causing the issue and has nothing to do with the conditionals.